# Is it possible to add/commit a file to the index of a local bare Git repo?

Tags: git, grit

I'm messing around with the Ruby Git gem... seeing how I can use it to manage/access a Gitosis server I'm running. Does anyone know if it is possible to add/commit files to a local bare repo, or will I need to set up a local 'normal' repo and use SSH to push it to the bare repo on the localhost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do this using low level **plumbing** commands:

```
$ generate_contents | git hash-object -t blob -w --stdin
$ git update-index --cacheinfo 100644 sha1 path
```

- *sha1* is result of previous command.
- `100644`: means an ordinary file.

But *bare repositories* are meant to be used only to push into or fetch from.  Bare repository doesn't need to have index at all!

Comment: git update-index returns `fatal: unknown option --cache-info`. git version 1.7.2.5

Comment: `git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 sha1 path` should work!

Comment: what does the `100644` mean?

Comment: @BenKoshy `100644` is an octal number representing permissions of the file, in this case an ordinary file (that is not executable file, or a symbolic link).

Answer (score 2):

You need a working tree to add a file to the index and commit it.
While it might be possible to change directly the internal content of a bare git repo through plumbing commands, I would really recommend setting up a normal clone, modify it and push the resulting commit back to the bare repo.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`git update-index --add --cachinfo`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) is important to add a file to the index, note that cacheinfo has a new syntax:

```
--cacheinfo <mode>,<object>,<path>
--cacheinfo <mode> <object> <path>
```

> Directly insert the specified info into the index.
>   For backward compatibility, you can also give these three arguments as three separate parameters, but **new users are encouraged to use a single-parameter form**.

See [commit ec160ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec160ae12b0ae938ed5076b9f604e88976fc429c) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster), March 2014, part of Git 2.0+:

> `update-index`: teach `--cacheinfo` a new syntax "`mode,sha1,path`"
>
> The "`--cacheinfo`" option is unusual in that it takes three option parameters.
>   An option with an optional parameter is bad enough.
>   An option with multiple parameters is simply insane.
>
> Introduce a new syntax that takes these three things concatenated together with a comma, which makes the command line syntax more uniform across subcommands, while retaining the traditional syntax for backward compatiblity.

---

Note: only git 2.0.X/2.1 (Q3 2014) takes care of the NULL case:
See [commit c8e1ee4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8e1ee4f2c8e28b7eef824248f09ba37599593d7) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff):

> Running "`git update-index --cacheinfo`" without any further arguments results in a segfault rather than an error message. [Commit ec160ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec160ae12b0ae938ed5076b9f604e88976fc429c) (update-index: teach `--cacheinfo` a new syntax "`mode,sha1,path`", 2014-03-23) added code to examine the format of the argument, but forgot to handle the NULL case.
>
> Returning an error from the parser is enough, since we then treat it as an old-style "`--cacheinfo <mode> <sha1> <path>`", and complain that we have less than 3 arguments to read.